# How to achieve this effect on hover in canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas

When you click on the hamburger menu, the menu appears. When you hover on text right side a photo on left  change with effect. My question is: How achieve this effect. Link to page: https://delcambio.me/en/gruppo/home

I inspect this element and i discover that is canvas, but i dont know how achiecve this effect.

Comment: This is a variation of warping created by slicing an image horizontally into many pieces and staggering the animation of those pieces onto the stage. You can use the canvas to do both the slicing & animation. Check out [context.drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a standard effect that browsers have out of the box. They have done some serious work of their own to achieve it. Quite possibly it involves WebGL, although I don't know. I also don't know if this effect has a name (probably not) so I can't point you in any direction.

My advice is to study closer their webpage. It's definitely Javascript that does it, so inspect the event handlers and Javascript sources until you find what you're looking for. Sorry, it won't be quick and easy.